# Resize Form while keeping aspect ratio

Tags: delphi, events, forms

I have a Window, in which i display a picture. I want the user to be able to resize this window, but
keep it in the same aspect ratio than the image, so no big empty areas appear on the window.

What i tried is something like this in the OnResize event:

```
DragWidth := Width;
DragHeight := Height;

//Calculate corresponding size with aspect ratio
//...
//Calculated values are now in CalcWidth and CalcHeight

Width := CalcWidth;
Height := CalcHeight;
```

The Problem with this is, that the window flashes during the resize dragging between the original resize size and the calculated, since the OnResize event is afaik called after the resize is already done (and painted once).

Do you know any solution for having a smooth aspect-ratio resizing?

Thanks for any Help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding the following handler for the OnCanResize event seemed to work very well for me:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCanResize(Sender: TObject; var NewWidth,
  NewHeight: Integer; var Resize: Boolean);
var
  AspectRatio:double;
begin
  AspectRatio:=Height/Width;
  NewHeight:=round(AspectRatio*NewWidth);
end;
```

You may of course want to change the method for calculating NewHeight and NewWidth. The following method feels intuitively "right" when I try it on a blank form:

```
  NewHeight:=round(0.5*(NewHeight+AspectRatio*NewWidth));
  NewWidth:=round(NewHeight/AspectRatio);
```

Comment: You've probably got this figured out already, but for anyone else interested, I would suggest keeping the aspect ratio for ClientWidth and ClientHeight constant instead of how I did it above. This will of course be a little more complicated.

Comment: Can you explain how to apply this method a little bit more, I'm very new to Delphi and I'm quite confused about how to setup this handler on OnCanResize event. Can you give me an example ? Highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Select the form in the design window, find the events tab on the left side, find OnCanResize and double click in the white cell to the right of the OnCanResize text. (Using Delphi 2009)

Comment: Thanks for the info, accidentally I already figured that out. My question now is , how to check if the window is being minimized, because if so, the form will not go to the taskbar, instead it will perform this: http://i.imgur.com/rVhci.png and I'm googling how to fix it but.. unsuccesfull till now.

Comment: That's an entirely different question that you are not likely to get a good answer to in a comment here.

Answer (score 2):

Recent delphi's have the [OnCanResize](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_TCanResizeEvent.html) event, that allow you to do exactly this. You can simply return the calculated NewWidth and NewHeight directly from the event.