# Resize form and maintain aspect ratio

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Similar question here: [Resize Form while keeping aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265746/resize-form-while-keeping-aspect-ratio)

Basically, what I want is to resize form and maintain its aspect ratio, but I want resizing to follow the cursor as well. The answer in the topic above provided solution that is half-satisfactory - it works, but resizing is working 2x slower than it should. When I start to resize the form by X axis, you can see where the cursor is, and what the form size is:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/SUIli7N.png]

I thought that since it resizes 2x slower, I should omit 0.5 multiplier in the code and it will work, but no dice. Here is the code that I'm using at the moment:

```
type
  TfrmTable = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCanResize(Sender: TObject; var NewWidth, NewHeight: Integer; var Resize: Boolean);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FAspectRatio: Double;
  public
  end;

var
  frmTable: TfrmTable;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmTable.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FAspectRatio := Width / Height;
end;

procedure TfrmTable.FormCanResize(Sender: TObject; var NewWidth, NewHeight: Integer; var Resize: Boolean);
begin
  NewHeight := Round(0.50 * (NewHeight + NewWidth / FAspectRatio));
  NewWidth := Round(NewHeight * FAspectRatio);
end;
```

I've tried another approach, by using something like this:

```
procedure TfrmTable.FormCanResize(Sender: TObject; var NewWidth, NewHeight: Integer; var Resize: Boolean);
begin
  if NewWidth <> Width then
    NewHeight := Round(NewWidth / FAspectRatio)
  else
    if NewHeight <> Height then
      NewWidth := Round(NewHeight * FAspectRatio);
end;
```

What this should do? Well, my thinking is that I first check if `NewWidth` is different than current `Width`, and if it is, that means user is resizing form by X axis. Then I should set `NewHeight` to appropriate value. Otherwise, I check if `NewHeight` is different than current `Height`, and set `NewWidth` value to its appropriate value. This also produces weird results, when I drag form by X axis, it seems to work, and as soon as I stop resizing, form returns to its original size - I concluded that once I stop resizing (let mouse button up), `FormCanResize()` event gets called with old `NewHeight` value, which then reverts form back to its old size.

Comment: I've done something like this in the past. Try adjusting one side in code, while the user adjusts the other.

Comment: That's what I've tried in second code snippet I've posted above.

Comment: The so-called 0.5 multiplier is to calculate a mean. Sum two heights, divide by two, that's the arithmetic mean. You should be precise about what you mean by "two times slower". Where does speed come into this? I can guess what you mean. I'd rather you were precise.

Comment: I believe that you wish to be able to resize an edge and have the other edge adapt to maintain aspect ratio. And for that to work with both horizontal and verical edges you need to know which edge is being sized. So you cannot have success with your current approach. I have some ideas but it will be a few hours before I can try them out and give you an answer.

Comment: I'm inclined to call [the other](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6265746/757830) a duplicate now.

Comment: @NGLN It might be worth re-writing this question a little though. I think that the answers here are the ones with value. So, yes, if this question is re-worded so that it does not refer to the other, and states the problem more clearly, then we should close the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct message to handle this is `WM_SIZING`:

> By processing this message, an application can monitor the size and
>   position of the drag rectangle and, if needed, change its size or
>   position.

```
procedure TForm1.WMSizing(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  case Message.wParam of
    WMSZ_LEFT, WMSZ_RIGHT, WMSZ_BOTTOMLEFT:
      with PRect(Message.LParam)^ do
        Bottom := Top + Round((Right-Left)/FAspectRatio);
    WMSZ_TOP, WMSZ_BOTTOM, WMSZ_TOPRIGHT, WMSZ_BOTTOMRIGHT:
      with PRect(Message.LParam)^ do
        Right := Left + Round((Bottom-Top)*FAspectRatio);
    WMSZ_TOPLEFT:
      with PRect(Message.LParam)^ do
        Top := Bottom - Round((Right-Left)/FAspectRatio);
  end;
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: Isn't calling inherited afterwards saying: "yeah, undo my changes if you want to"? I would prefer calling it in front. +1 btw

Comment: @NGLN No it is not. The default handling of `WM_SIZING` applies no constraints. Remember the `TMessage` parameter is passed by `var`.

Comment: @NGLN OK, I see what you mean. Sorry.

Comment: So, +1 for this, I approve

Comment: @NGLN - I guess it doesn't matter, could as well skip calling DefWindowProc altogether, but need to make sure no one acts on the message parameters in inheritance chain. Thanks for the edit, ..and the vote. :)

Comment: Thanks, I've already done something similar to your solution, but I couldn't think of a proper way to handle BOTTOMLEFT/TOPLEFT corners, your solution works just perfectly for those too :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do without auxiliary.

Here I use a simple integer field to store whether you size horizontally, vertically, or not at all. You could also declare an enumeration for that.

```
  ...
  private
    FAspectRatio: Double;
    FResizing: Integer;
    procedure WMExitSizeMove(var Message: TMessage); message WM_EXITSIZEMOVE;
  end;

...

procedure TForm1.FormCanResize(Sender: TObject; var NewWidth,
  NewHeight: Integer; var Resize: Boolean);
begin
  if FResizing = 0 then
    FResizing := Abs(NewHeight - Height) - Abs(NewWidth - Width);
  if FResizing < 0 then
    NewHeight := Round(NewWidth / FAspectRatio)
  else
    NewWidth := Round(NewHeight * FAspectRatio);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FAspectRatio := Width / Height;
end;

procedure TForm1.WMExitSizeMove(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  FResizing := 0;
end;
```

Comment: +1 However, I think the problem with this is that it places too much emphasis on that very first initial resize which, could well be a single delta in X, or a single delta in Y. I like what you are trying to do. My answer tries to switch between vertical or horizontal based resizing depending on the current state of the size.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take on this. Here I am trying to base the resize on width or height depending on which one has been moved the most.

```
type
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FAspectRatio: Double;
    FWidthAtStartOfSize: Integer;
    FHeightAtStartOfSize: Integer;
  protected
    procedure WMEnterSizeMove(var Message: TMessage); message WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE;
    procedure WMSizing(var Message: TMessage); message WM_SIZING;
  end;

procedure TMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FAspectRatio := Width / Height;
end;

procedure TMyForm.WMEnterSizeMove(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  FWidthAtStartOfSize := Width;
  FHeightAtStartOfSize := Height;
end;

procedure TMyForm.WMSizing(var Message: TMessage);
var
  SizeBasedOnWidth: Boolean;
  NewHeight, NewWidth: Integer;
  Rect: PRect;
begin
  inherited;

  Rect := PRect(Message.LParam);
  case Message.wParam of
  WMSZ_LEFT, WMSZ_RIGHT:
    Rect.Bottom := Rect.Top + Round(Rect.Width/FAspectRatio);
  WMSZ_TOP, WMSZ_BOTTOM:
    Rect.Right := Rect.Left + Round(Rect.Height*FAspectRatio);
  WMSZ_TOPLEFT, WMSZ_TOPRIGHT, WMSZ_BOTTOMLEFT, WMSZ_BOTTOMRIGHT:
    begin
      if Rect.Width>FWidthAtStartOfSize then begin
        SizeBasedOnWidth := Rect.Height<MulDiv(FHeightAtStartOfSize, Rect.Width, FWidthAtStartOfSize)
      end else begin
        SizeBasedOnWidth := Rect.Width>MulDiv(FWidthAtStartOfSize, Rect.Height, FHeightAtStartOfSize);
      end;
      if SizeBasedOnWidth then begin
        NewHeight := Round(Rect.Width/FAspectRatio);
        case Message.wParam of
        WMSZ_TOPLEFT, WMSZ_TOPRIGHT:
          Rect.Top := Rect.Bottom - NewHeight;
        WMSZ_BOTTOMLEFT, WMSZ_BOTTOMRIGHT:
          Rect.Bottom := Rect.Top + NewHeight;
        end;
      end else begin
        NewWidth := Round(Rect.Height*FAspectRatio);
        case Message.wParam of
        WMSZ_TOPLEFT, WMSZ_BOTTOMLEFT:
          Rect.Left := Rect.Right - NewWidth;
        WMSZ_TOPRIGHT, WMSZ_BOTTOMRIGHT:
          Rect.Right := Rect.Left + NewWidth;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I quite like Sertac's answer. Short and sweet. I've started my code based on his. But Sertac's code takes sides when you resize in the corners. For a particular corner it always favours one of vertical or horizontal. Here I have tried to be agnostic and allow corner resizes to be based on either horizontal or vertical edges, depending on just how you perform the dragging.

Do note that no algorithm will be entirely satisfactory. In fact, I think if I were doing this, I would very much consider disabling corner resize.

Comment: @Sertac Thanks for the edit. As you can tell, I was trying out your code!

Comment: You're welcome. I quite like the way the cursor is clipped in your answer. Need to workout something for resizing from left etc.. but I like it.

Comment: I _want_ to give you +1, but this solution has some oddities: no shrink when sizing right or bottom, moving instead of sizing when sizing top, left, topleft, bottomleft, topright. In short, only bottomright performs well.

Comment: @NGLN Thanks for that. Yes, I only tested bottom right. Silly of me. I think that the latest update behaves well.

Comment: So you too gave up on `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` after all :)

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Yes. It's no good! As I commented a few hours ago, "you need to know which edge is being sized." So, `WMSizing` is the thing. I'm frustrated that I cannot make my code any simpler. It's surely possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting OSX with firemonkey, the respective API provides an easy way to lock the aspect ratio:

```
uses {...} FMX.Platform.Mac, Macapi.AppKit, Macapi.CocoaTypes;

// ...

procedure TMyForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  var Window: NSWindow;
begin
  if not FRunOnce then
  begin
    FRunOnce := true;
    Window := WindowHandleToPlatform(Handle).Wnd;
    Window.setContentAspectRatio(NSSize(TPointF.Create(ClientWidth, ClientHeight)));
  end;
end;
```